# How to import a Winforms settings file at run time

Tags: c#, winforms

I am the dev of a c# **winforms** app which contains a lot of settings. These settings get tweaked and optimized by a domain specialist user/tester.

The user is able to send me his app.config file from time to time and I would like to load and activate his settings ***at run time*** (even better, selected ones) on my side in *one fell swoop*, given that I have his app.config file to hand. In other words I want to code an 'Import settings' option.

I am aware I can just overwrite my own app.config with his, but surely I would have to do this prior to starting my app?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After you replace the existing current App.Config with the updated one.

You can open the current configuration in code and read the current value like below

```
var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
MyUpdatedValue = configuration.AppSettings.Settings["myUpdatedValue"].Value as ...
```